# Make sub list for my list-view items in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have created a program that has two list View and a panel for displaying details of second list items. first list view is displaying categories.

[image]

The first list view items are created using Observable Collection and a class like this:

```
public class Catagory : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int id;
    private string name;

    public int ID
    { 
        get { return id; }
        set { id = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; OnPropertyChanged() ;}
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return this.Name.ToString();
    }    

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string Caller = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        { 
            PropertyChanged(this,new PropertyChangedEventArgs(Caller));
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Return a list of catergory
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static ObservableCollection<Catagory> GetCategories()
    {
        var cats = new ObservableCollection<Catagory>();
        cats.Add(new Catagory() {id=1,name="Softwares" });
        cats.Add(new Catagory() { id = 2, name = "Books" });
        cats.Add(new Catagory() { id = 3, name = "Movies" });
        cats.Add(new Catagory() { id = 4, name = "Learning Videos" });
        cats.Add(new Catagory() { id = 5, name = "Audio" });
        return cats;
    }    
}
```

And in the main window I use this to fill list with predefined items:

```
groups.ItemsSource= Catagory.GetCategories();
```

**groups** is my list view component name.

The thing I wanted to do is that by clicking on each item in group list view the second list view display items that belongs to that category item. but I have no clue even where to start.
I want to know how this would be for large amount of data. 
Please Help me.

**XAML**:

```
<Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="95*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="25"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <!--lists-->
        <ListView x:Name="groups" />
        <ListView x:Name="items" Grid.Column="1" Style="{DynamicResource ItemsList}" />

        <!--ToolBars-->
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" x:Name="group_tools" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1"  Style="{StaticResource ToolBarBackground}">
            <Button Content="+" Style="{StaticResource ToolBarButtons}" Click="btn_AddCategory"/>
            <Button Content="-" Style="{DynamicResource ToolBarButtons}" Click="btn_RemoveFromCategory"/>
            <Button Content="*" Style="{DynamicResource ToolBarButtons}"/>
        </StackPanel>

        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" x:Name="items_tools" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"   Style="{StaticResource ToolBarBackground}">
            <Button Content="+" Style="{StaticResource ToolBarButtons}"/>
            <Button Content="-" Style="{DynamicResource ToolBarButtons}"/>
            <Button Content="*" Style="{DynamicResource ToolBarButtons}"/>
        </StackPanel>

        <StackPanel  Orientation="Horizontal" x:Name="preview_pane" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1"   Style="{StaticResource ToolBarBackground}">
            <Label  FontSize="10" Foreground="Gray" FontWeight="Bold" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center">Version: Just UI</Label>
        </StackPanel>

        <!-- spliters -->
        <GridSplitter Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left"   Width="1"/>
        <GridSplitter Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left"   Width="1"/>

        <!--Spliters-->

    </Grid>
```

Comment: Just to make sure i get you right 
you nwant to click on "Software/Books/Learning..." and then display something different  in the middle?
then you should go with a tabcontrol
And if you want to have subitems in your listview you should check out treeviews i guess
If that doesnt help i dont understand what you are trying to achive...

Comment: @DenisSchaf every item in first list has a list of children. I wanted to by clicking on Items of first list children being displayed in middle list view and by clicking on any child the data of that child being displayed on third part. is this hard to achieve in list view?

Comment: Could you provide some WPF code? I'd go for an `ObservableCollection` as `ItemSource` for every section implemented as a `ListBox`.

Comment: Are you following MVVM? or code behind?,

Comment: @FredM yes. i add main window xaml to my question body.

Comment: @fhnaseer I am beginner in mvvm pattern .but if your answer has details that i could follow,  I will accept it.

Comment: If you want to use the MVVM pattern, have a look at binding to properties. In your case also to binding the `ObservableCollection` to the `ItemSource` of the `ListView`.

Comment: (not mvvm) you need to handle event when item is selected in first `ListView`. In that handler you can populate data of second `ListView`,